# When should I lock a static instance in multithreaded singletons when using a setter?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Trying to understand when it's considered best-practice to lock a static variable or not.  Is the static Instance setter thread-safe?  If not, should it be and why (what's the consequence of not making it thread-safe)?

```
class MyClass
{
    private static MyClass _instance;

    private static readonly object _padlock = new object();

    public static MyClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance == null)
            {
                lock(_padlock)
                {
                    if(_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new MyClass();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
        set => _instance = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have a setter? Is it so that you can replace `MyClass` with a fresh one at some point?

Comment: Correct. It's going to be used as part of the ambient context pattern where I'm implementing a factory class. I can't see a reason to lock it, but it seems like it's not thread safe either.

Comment: I recommend hiding the setter behind a separate appropriately named method to discourage random assignments, as what may happen.. also no, it’s *not* thread-safe.

Comment: I agree it's not thread-safe, but the assignment being atomic briefly confused me. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called *Double-checked locking*.

However, *Double-checked locking* requires that the underlying field is `volatile`<sup>1</sup>.

In short, the assignment is atomic, yet it will need to be *synchronized* (full fence, via a lock) across the different cores/CPUs. The reason why is another core concurrently reading the value might get an outdated value cached<sup>1</sup>.

There are several ways to make the code thread-safe:

- Avoid *double-checked locking*, and simply perform everything within the `lock` statement.
- Make the field *volatile* using the `volatile` keyword.
- Use the `Lazy` class, which is guaranteed to be *thread-safe*.

<sub>**Note** : The completely unguarded setter further adds a complication<sup>3</sup>..</sub>

However, in your case, using *double-checked locking* will probably work fine with a single check and lock with the `volatile` field, yet i think your best bet is to just full `lock` everything and be safe

```
public static MyClass Instance
{
    get
    {
         lock(_padlock)
         {
             if(_instance == null)
                 _instance = new MyClass();
             return _instance;
         }

    }
    set 
    {
         lock(_padlock)
         {
             _instance = value;
         }
    } 
}
```

<sub>***Note*** : Yes it will incur a performance penalty</sub>

---

**Reference**

- <sup>1</sup> [Double-checked lock is not thread-safe](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/CSHARP/Double-checked+lock+is+not+thread-safe)
- <sup>2</sup>[The famous double-checked locking technique in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394898/double-checked-locking-in-net)
- <sup>3</sup> Comment from [@user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/user2864740)

---

**Additional Resources**

- [Double-checked locking in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394898/double-checked-locking-in-net)
- [The famous double-checked locking technique in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668216/the-famous-double-checked-locking-technique-in-c-sharp)
- [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the double-checked locking and prefer using Lazy<T> instead, but this is a rare case where I need a setter. In the past I've used the volatile keyword, but with int (for example).  So you DO recommend locking the setter, making it thread-safe?

Comment: @ChrisGessler yes you will need to lock the setter as well.

Comment: @MichaelRandall - Can you explain the negatives of not locking it? For example, could I end up with corrupt memory? Will it crash the exe or would I simply receive a cached (old) copy of the object? I tried crashing the app with thousands of threads and it couldn't.

Comment: @ChrisGessler No the assignments are atomic, worst case is you end up with the wrong reference, you think you are getting the default, but its a different instantiation of default, or you think you have set it, but you end up with the default, or vice versa

Comment: @MichaelRandall - I agree.  Safety first!  Thanks for you help!

Comment: Nitpicking: `However, Double-checked locking requires that the underlying field is volatile. In short, the assignment is atomic, yet it will need to be synchronized (full fence) across the different cores/CPUs` -> volatile in .net does not emit a full fence. `lock` does though.

Comment: @KevinGosse yeah it was a little loose when i read it back. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that locks or no locks (on the setter), you will always have an issue of timing. Imagine these scenarios:

1. You have a lock on the setter but a call to the getter comes in just before the lock is engaged. The caller gets the old instance.
2. You have a lock on the setter but a call to the getter comes in just after the lock is engaged. The caller waits for the lock to be free, and then gets the new instance.
3. You don't have a lock on the setter, and the call comes in just *before* you replace the instance. The caller gets the old instance.
4. You don't have a lock on the setter, and the call comes in just *after* you replace the instance. The caller gets the new instance.

With locks and without locks, it's a matter of timing which instance the caller receives.

The only issue I can see is if you want to be able to set `Instance` to `null`. If that's the case, your current code will not work because `_instance` could be changed between the `if` statement and returning it. You can resolve this by taking a copy of the reference:

```
public static MyClass Instance
{
    get
    {
        var instanceSafeRef = _instance;
        if(instanceSafeRef == null)
        {
            lock(_padlock)
            {
                if(_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new MyClass();
                }
                instanceSafeRef = _instance;
            }
        }
        return instanceSafeRef;
    }
    set => _instance = value;
}
```