# InMemoryCache return old cache during refreshing (long running ) cache .net framework 4.8

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I implemented following InMemoryCache mechanism, how I can be sure that if fetching data for new cache takes to many time, other threads would be able to get old cache data without problem?

```
public class InMemoryCache <TData>
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lockSlim = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private readonly Timer _refreshTimer;
    private DateTime _lastRefreshTime;
    private readonly int _refreshDataIntervalInMinutes;
    private TData _cachedData;
    private readonly Func <TData> _dataFetchingMethod;
    private bool _isRefreshing;

    public InMemoryCache(int ? refreshDataIntervalInMinutes, Func <TData> dataFetchingMethod)
    {
        _dataFetchingMethod = dataFetchingMethod;
        if (ShouldStartTimer(refreshDataIntervalInMinutes))
        {
            if (refreshDataIntervalInMinutes != null) _refreshDataIntervalInMinutes = refreshDataIntervalInMinutes.Value;
            _refreshTimer = new Timer(RefreshData, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_refreshDataIntervalInMinutes), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_refreshDataIntervalInMinutes));
        }
        RefreshData(null);
    }
    private static bool ShouldStartTimer(int ? refreshDataIntervalInMinutes)
    {
        return refreshDataIntervalInMinutes != null;
    }

    public TData GetData()
    {
        _lockSlim.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            if (DateTime.Now - _lastRefreshTime > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_refreshDataIntervalInMinutes) && TryEnterRefreshLock())
            {
                RefreshData(null);
            }
            return _cachedData;
        }
        finally
        {
            _lockSlim.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    private bool TryEnterRefreshLock()
    {

            int isRefreshing = _isRefreshing ? 1 : 0;

            //for atomic check

            return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isRefreshing, 1, 0) == 0;

    }

    private void RefreshData(object state)
    {
        _lockSlim.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        try
        {
            if (_isRefreshing) return;
            
            _lockSlim.EnterWriteLock();
            _isRefreshing = true;
            try
            {
                _cachedData = _dataFetchingMethod.Invoke();
                _lastRefreshTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
            finally
            {
                _isRefreshing = false;
                _lockSlim.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _lockSlim.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }
    }

    public void ManualRefresh()
    {
        Task.Run(() => RefreshData(null));
    }
}




public static class InMemoryCacheInstance
    {
        private static readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim LockSlim = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
        private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> Instances = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

        /// <summary>
        /// creates an instance
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="refreshDataIntervalInMinutes">if not null then creates timer to refresh</param>
        /// <param name="dataFetchingMethod"></param>
        /// <returns>returns cached data</returns>
        public static InMemoryCache<T> CreateInstance<T>(int? refreshDataIntervalInMinutes, Func<T> dataFetchingMethod)
        {
            LockSlim.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                var instance = new InMemoryCache<T>(refreshDataIntervalInMinutes, dataFetchingMethod);
                Instances[typeof(T)] = instance;
                return instance;
            }
            finally
            {
                LockSlim.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        public static InMemoryCache<T> GetInstance<T>()
        {
            LockSlim.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                if (Instances.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var instance)) return (InMemoryCache<T>)instance;

                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                LockSlim.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason to not use [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/) package for caching?

Comment: I have  two trigger to refresh cache, timer trigger and manual trigger. Do you mean I can use this package fully for this purpose? or I should use it inside my implementation? Do you see  any issue /risk on my code?

Comment: @KamilIbadov yes. You can set new value "manually" whenever you want. And it supports absolute expiration (i.e. "by timer").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bit to unpack here.

1. You refresh asynchronously on a timed basis after construction.
2. You can refresh on-demand with a call to `ManualRefresh()`.
3. You may refresh if a time window is exceeded when checked in `GetData()`.
4. You might want to refresh before anything important happens (see **Other Thoughts**).
5. You seem to be OK with returning (hopefully) slightly stale data.

This seems a bit much. I'd consider removing one of these (probably #1 or #3), but that is indirectly related to the main strategy.

So, main strategy? The obvious thing would be to use [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/) or similar open source package. You could even go with a `ConcurrentDictionary` with some customization.

But...

You can vastly simplify your custom approach because you have a cache that can hold only one item. That one item can be replaced and/or read atomically without any concurrency issues<sup>*</sup>. This is OK for your purposes because you're OK with possibly stale data.

Consider this implementation:

```cs
public class InMemoryCache<TData> : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly object _lock = new();
    private readonly Timer _refreshTimer;
    private DateTime _lastRefreshTime;
    private readonly int _refreshDataIntervalInMinutes;
    private TData _cachedData;
    private readonly Func<TData> _dataFetchingMethod;
    private bool _isRefreshing;

    public InMemoryCache(int? refreshDataIntervalInMinutes, Func<TData> dataFetchingMethod)
    {
        _dataFetchingMethod = dataFetchingMethod;
        if (ShouldStartTimer(refreshDataIntervalInMinutes))
        {
            if (refreshDataIntervalInMinutes != null) _refreshDataIntervalInMinutes = refreshDataIntervalInMinutes.Value;
            _refreshTimer = new Timer(RefreshData, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_refreshDataIntervalInMinutes), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_refreshDataIntervalInMinutes));
        }
        RefreshData(null);
    }
    private static bool ShouldStartTimer(int? refreshDataIntervalInMinutes)
    {
        return refreshDataIntervalInMinutes != null;
    }

    public TData GetData()
    {
        // checking outside the lock is fine. _cachedData may be stale or not
        if (_isRefreshing)
            return _cachedData;

        // only a simple lock is needed to check for and/or kick off a refresh
        lock (_lock)
        {
            // we are able to take the lock, but there's a refresh in progress. return whatever we have, which may suddenly be fresh, but likely stale
            if (_isRefreshing)
                return _cachedData;

            if (DateTime.Now - _lastRefreshTime > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_refreshDataIntervalInMinutes))
            {
                // kick off the refresh asynchronously
                ManualRefresh();
            }
        }

        // this may or may not return stale data; either way, no lock needed
        return _cachedData;
    }

    private void RefreshData(object state)
    {
        // quick check. if we are refreshing, leave as there is no need to over-refresh
        // if we are not, let's mark that we are going to refresh, and then continue...
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_isRefreshing) return;
            _isRefreshing = true;
        }

        bool wasRefreshed = false;
        try
        {
            // the refresh can be done outside the lock because we are already protected by
            // the code above, and because we are only writing to a temporary location, not
            // the cached location
            var freshData = _dataFetchingMethod.Invoke();
            wasRefreshed = true;

            // now we need to write to the cached location. this is atomic and also does not
            // require a lock
            _cachedData = freshData;
        }
        finally
        {
            // indicate we are done
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (wasRefreshed)
                    _lastRefreshTime = DateTime.Now;
                _isRefreshing = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void ManualRefresh() => Task.Run(() => RefreshData(null));

    public void Dispose() => _refreshTimer.Dispose();

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync() => await _refreshTimer.DisposeAsync();
}
```

Only a single briefly held lock is needed to guard and check the cache instance's state. No other locking is required, whether a regular `Monitor` or a reader/writer lock, because reference assignment in .NET is guaranteed atomic<sup>*</sup>.

Let me stress the "briefly" part as this gets to the heart of your requirement: readers can still read *even while refresh is happening*.

When the cache is refreshing, it's really refreshing a temporary reference (taking however long is needed) freely allowing readers to get whatever is in `_cachedData` during this time. Furthermore, multiple concurrent refreshes (aka redundant refreshes) are blocked with checks to `_isRefreshed`. This holds true whether the refreshes occur manually, via timer, or both.

#### Other Thoughts

- I added the dispose constructs so you can dispose of the timer when the time is right (e.g. application shutdown).
- The solution above fails in one case: when there is no data in the cache when `GetData()` is called. This can be fixed by

  - adding a synchronous cache-warming method to be called at application startup time, prior to when the cache will be used in practice. This is a common practice.
  - refreshing the data synchronously during a timer tick or on-demand after startup. *However, if you do this, you must extend the duration of the held lock, defeating the purpose of getting stale data while refreshing*.
- You don't need the `volatile` keyword for `_cachedData`. That's meant for scenarios where multiple threads could simultaneously change the variable. The `lock` we're using prevents simultaneous refresh.
- You don't need to use the [Interlocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=net-8.0) methods as, again, refresh is happening single-threadedly to a temporary location, and you're not doing any "test/set" functionality to `_cachedData` in any single thread -- only the atomic reads from many threads with a write from a single thread that itself is atomic<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>*</sup> This is because .NET guarantees that a reference, when read, is atomic and, when written, occurs atomically (see [Atomicity of Variable References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#96-atomicity-of-variable-references)). There is no such thing as reference pointing to A, when changed to point to B, will ever be a reference to half-A/half-B (i.e. a garbage reference). It's either A or B and that is fine for your scenario. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840376/is-replacing-the-value-of-a-member-variable-thread-safe) gives some more context.

Comment: Some newer C# syntax used and .NET 8... but all of this holds true for .NET Framework 4.8 unless someone finds something I missed!

Comment: Thank you for great answer and explanation! Can you also review my cache instance class ? which uses static dictionary?  I edited question description @Kit