# how to update class that changes frequently? reinstatiate every time or just update fields?

Tags: c#

I need to update `InstrumentInfo` class frequently. I update this class from one thread and access (read) from another.

I have `Instrument` class. For each `Instrument` class I need to maintain `InstrumentInfo`:

```
// omit class Instrument as not improtant

public class InstrumentInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TradingStatus Status { get; set; }
    public decimal MinStep;
    public double ValToday;
    public decimal BestBuy;
    public decimal BestSell;
}

public class DerivativeInfo : InstrumentInfo
{
    public DateTime LastTradeDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public string UnderlyingTicker { get; set; }
}

// i do have several more subclasses
```

I do have two options:

1. Create only one `InstrumentInfo` for each `Instrument`. When some field updates, for example `BestBuy` just update value of this field. Clients should obtain `InstrumentInfo` only once and use it during entire application lifetime.
2. On each update create new instance of `InstrumentInfo`. Clients should obtain every time the most recent copy of InstrumentInfo.

With `1` I do need to lock, because `decimal` `DateTime` `string` update is not guaranteed to be atomic. But I don't need to reinstatiate object.

With `2` I don't need to lock at all, as `reference` update is atomic. But I likely will use more memory and I will probably create more work for GC because every time I need to instatiate new object (and initialize all fields).

`1` implementation

```
    private InstrumentInfo[] instrumentInfos = new InstrumentInfo[Constants.MAX_INSTRUMENTS_NUMBER_IN_SYSTEM];

    // invoked from different threads
    public InstrumentInfo GetInstrumentInfo(Instrument instrument)
    {
        lock (instrumentInfos) {
            var result = instrumentInfos[instrument.Id];
            if (result == null) {
                result = new InstrumentInfo();
                instrumentInfos[instrument.Id] = result;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    ...........
    InstrumentInfo ii = GetInstrumentInfo(instrument);
    lock (ii) {
        ii.BestSell = BestSell;
    }
```

`2` implementation:

```
    private InstrumentInfo[] instrumentInfos = new InstrumentInfo[Constants.MAX_INSTRUMENTS_NUMBER_IN_SYSTEM];

    // get and set are invoked from different threads
    // but i don't need to lock at all!!! as reference update is atomic
    public void SetInstrumentInfo(Instrument instrument, InstrumentInfo info)
    {
        if (instrument == null || info == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        instrumentInfos[instrument.Id] = info;
    }

    // get and set are invoked from different threads
    public InstrumentInfo GetInstrumentInfo(Instrument instrument)
    {
        return instrumentInfos[instrument.Id];
    }
    ....
    InstrumentInfo ii = new InstrumentInfo {
        Name = ..
        TradingStatus = ...
        ...
        BestSell = 
    }

    SetInstrumentInfo(instrument, ii); // replace InstrumentInfo
```

So what do you think? I want to use approach `2` because I like code without locks! Am I correct that I do not need `lock` at all as I just replace reference? Do you aggree that `2` is preferred? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: just in case you *do* lock, lock on a `private static readonly object` and not on your array of instrument infos - just as a defensive coding practice.

Comment: @codesparkle - Locking on a `static` object would lead to (much) more contention than necessary. The current approach (`ii` is not the array) looks OK.

Comment: @HenkHolterman he is locking on `lock (instrumentInfos) {` which is an array. `ii` has nothing to do with it. But you're right, it's unnecessary and bad to make it static. readonly would do.

Comment: You're right, I was looking at the other lock. The `lock (instrumentInfos)` might not be needed at all.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it need to guarantee that exactly one instance is created. If GetInstrumentInfo is called from different threads one thread may obtain copy which is not valid. Of course code may be refactored so I `lock` only if `result == null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With `2` I don't need to lock at all, as reference update is atomic. But I likely will use more memory and I will probably create more work for GC because

No, your option `1` is just as likely to cause more load on the GC (by promoting more objects to the next generation).

1. Use the most sensible, maintainable form. In this case, create new objects.
2. Do not optimize based on what you 'think' might be slower. Use a profiler.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider several unrelated points.

1. When you can go without locks, you should go without them, of course. And when you go for multithreading, prefer immutable objects.
2. On the other side, immutable objects

   - strain memory
   - are considered "anti-OOP"
   - may be incorrectly consumed by client code (because people are not used working with them)
3. Your second approach still requires some concurrency handling strategy, because several threads may `set` infos with different starting assumptions.
4. <strike>I am not sure that reference assignment is atomic. If it were, why does CLR have `Interlocked.Exchange<T>`?</strike> Thanks to Henk Holterman for pointing this out.

Comment: since *when* are immutable objects considered "anti-OOP"?

Comment: Re 4) reference-assignment is documented to be atomic.

Comment: @codesparkle since invention of holy wars between object-worshippers and function-worshippers. Not that I agree with any of sides, I just warn of possible edge point.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I tried to find this in documentation, but could not. Would you please provide a link?

Comment: This counts as official: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2193445 , and Guffa has a link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2192176

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks a lot. I doubt that anything could be more official than Lippert's answer.

Comment: thanks guys. I can't mark both answers as correct so I upvote this one.