# Understanding class level variable usage in Multi-Threading C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables, scope, field

I want to know the consequence of using a class level variable across different functions in a multi-threaded app.

I am creating a class variable and sharing it across get and set function. 
The variable is bound to have a value like :

```
"testuser-2.3" {username-projectversion}
```

Code:

```
class Test()
{
    private string key;

public Get(string something)
{
    key = setToSOmething();
}

public Set(string something)
{
    key = setToSOmething();
}

}
```

Is this code prone to fail in multithreaded environments? Like if two users are accessing diffrent versions of the project, will the "key" value will be diffrent at any random given point?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A project is, in most cases, just a collection of in-compiled files. The files need to be compiled into, typically, an executable. An executable is, often, just a file on disk and can be duplicated. Even a single copy of the executable can be run multiple times, creating a process each time. In order for two users to access the same variable in memory, they need to be accessing the same process. So, strictly speaking, two users of different versions of the project would not interfere with each other.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know the consequence of using a class level variable across different functions in a multi-threaded app.

What you're doing in your code will work, sort of, but **it doesn't demonstrate the consequence of allowing multiple threads to modify a variable.**  It doesn't answer your question. It just means that you'll be okay with the particular thing you're doing with this particular variable.

In this case you're just assigning a different reference to your `string` variable. That's safe, in a way. You won't get any mangled strings, but it means that you don't know which string a given function will get when it reads the variable. In some scenarios that's not so bad, but it's a little chaotic.

The problem occurs when multiple threads interact with your variable in a way that isn't thread safe.

Here's a really simple test method I wrote without actually knowing what was going to happen:

```
public class MultithreadedStringTest
{
    private string _sharedString;
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoesntMessUpStrings()
    {
        var inputStrings = "The quick fox jumped over the lazy brown dog".Split(' ');
        var random= new Random();
        Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000), x =>
        {
            _sharedString += " " + inputStrings[random.Next(0, 9)];
        });
        var outputStrings = _sharedString.Trim().Split(' ');
        var nonMangledStrings = outputStrings.Count(s => inputStrings.Contains(s));
        Assert.AreEqual(1000, outputStrings.Length, 
            $"We lost {1000-outputStrings.Length} strings!");
        Assert.AreEqual(nonMangledStrings, outputStrings.Length, 
            $"{outputStrings.Length-nonMangledStrings} strings got mangled.");
    }
}
```

I'm starting with 10 words, and then, in a `Parallel.Each` loop appending 1000 words selected from those 10 to a single string from concurrent threads.

I expected the string to get mangled. It didn't. Instead what happened is that out of my 1000 words that I added, typically a few hundred just got lost.

> We lost 495 strings!

Obviously that's not the particular operation that you're performing. But what it shows is that when we perform concurrent operations, we need to know that we're either calling a thread safe method or we're using some mechanism to prevent conflicts. We want to know how our code will behave and not cross our fingers and hope for the best.

If we're not careful with it the results will be unpredictable and inconsistent. It might work when you test it and fail later, and when it does it will be difficult to diagnose because you won't be able to see it happen.

Comment: Yeah, attempting to treat get and set (which this code is effectively doing with `+=`) as a single atomic operation is certainly the biggest danger, imo.  I think the big problem with code like this is that it's never *intuitive* that you are treating get and set as a single atomic operation.

Comment: The risk with an example like this is that it might draw attention to the mechanics of the example. The code I wrote doesn't do anything either useful or well - it's more like a crash test dummy to see how it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the fact that `Get` and `Set` are both *setting* `key` in your code...

This code won't be prone to failure because of the nature of `string`.  It's an immutable class, and the data is basically constructed elsewhere, and *then* your `key` assignment happens, as a single, atomic operation.  (It's a reference or basically a pointer assignment).

So...even if you were to have two setters, `key` will always reference a valid string.  Depending on the *use* of this code, though, the order in which the assignments actually happen could be counterintuitive.  Say your `get` actually returns the string...`set(get() + "X")` could eventually lose Xes if called multiple times from multiple threads.  Because all the `get` calls could get the same old string and perform the string addition on that.  But this is you assuming set AND get together are an atomic operation.  The accepted answer here:
[reference assignment is atomic so why is Interlocked.Exchange(ref Object, Object) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192124/reference-assignment-is-atomic-so-why-is-interlocked-exchangeref-object-object)
explains this better than I'm doing.

The contrary example would be if you were to use `StringBuilder` and actually modify the data inside the class...*that* would not be thread-safe and would certainly require a lock.

Updating answer to explain my reasoning behind my argument that the OP's code is fundamentally thread-safe considered on its own.  Consider the following code which attempts to add thread-safety:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    private object emergencyLock = new object();
    private string _status;
    public string status
    {
      get
      {
        //make sure if an emergency is happening we get the best possible string.
        lock (emergencyLock)
        {
          return _status;
        }
      }
      set
      {
        //we could also lock here instead of in GetEmergencyString()..which would fix the get+set=atomic issue
        _status = value;
      }
    }
    private string GetEmergencyString()
    {
      //this function understands an emergency is happening
      lock (emergencyLock)
      {
        //Maybe I'm fetching this string from a database, or building it by hand
        //It takes a while...We'll simulate this here
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return "Oh crap, emergency!";
      }
    }
    private void Normal_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      status = "Nothing much going on.";
    }

    private void Emergency_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      //GetEmergencyString() is evaluated first..finally returns a string, 
      //and THEN the assignment occurs as a single operation
      status = GetEmergencyString();
    }
  }
```

I'll make the following points about this code:

It *does* prevent a status seeker from getting a "boring" status during an emergency.  It also potentially forces the status seeker to wait a full second before getting that status...Effectively solving nothing, most likely.

Also consider that even single-threaded, there's a fundamental issue here.  The fundamental issue is NOT thread safety (in my opinion).  The fundamental issue is delay.  Better solutions?  Fixing the delay.  *Active* notification of the new state..Events, pubsub, etc.  A state machine.  Even a `volatile bool IsEmergency` is much better than the "thread-safety" I've added.  Any active, intelligent logic in the code.  Maybe you don't want the emergency state to be overwritten by the normal state?  Again...not a threading issue.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. If user A waits for Test.Get() to return "Safties on" before proceeding with some task, what does it mean when User B uses Test.Set("Live ammo") mid execution? Maybe nothing, or maybe something bad. String is immutable, but this class is not.

Comment: User A is either left with the old string or the new one.  User A definitely gets a valid string.

Comment: I guess we're back to definitions. What does the OP mean by fail?

Comment: @eisenpony - Well, I think your first comment on this question is pretty on-point.  I'm not even sure multi-threading is an actual issue here.  As far as your question, if the user gets the old string, it's because key hasn't been set to the new one yet.  If the user gets the new one...it has.  It's hard to imagine either of those scenarios being a failure.  It could be a failure of my imagination, though.  I'd be interested in even a somewhat contrived example.

Comment: well, failure could mean different things .. To your point, there will always be a "valid" string from a technical point of view, so there probably won't be a runtime error unless User B is nasty and calls Test.Set(null). But, back to my contrived example, if User A starts a task that involves aiming a weapon for 5 seconds and then firing it, they might be very surprised when things start blowing up. That's a different kind of failure entirely.

Comment: @eisenpony - My last job was medical devices, and we actually had a scenario *sort of* like what you're describing.  Thing is, if you're storing those kind of states in a string....you've got issues.  Thread synchronization at a higher level is called for at that point.  Also...even that stuff you're talking about seconds or milliseconds, not clock cycles.