# Combining Interlocked.Increment and Volatile.Write

Tags: c#, concurrency, volatile

I've been looking at the source code of System.Reactive ([here](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/e483d14c0c090ae739626af547c72a0a30c23797/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Internal/ScheduledObserver.cs#L657)), and it's taken me down a rabbit hole to this place, where there is a `Volatile.Read` followed by `Interlocked.CompareExchange`, on the same variable:

```
if (Volatile.Read(ref _runDrainOnce) == 0
    && Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _runDrainOnce, 1, 0) == 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

As I read it, the logic of this is "if runDrainOnce is 0 and, if it was zero before I changed it to 1". Is there something subtle here? Why is the first check not redundant?

*(Even more mind-boggling, there is a `lock` and a `Monitor.Pulse` in the same function. Was this the result of a bet? :))*

The whole function:

```
private void Schedule()
{
    // Schedule the suspending drain once
    if (Volatile.Read(ref _runDrainOnce) == 0
        && Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _runDrainOnce, 1, 0) == 0)
    {
        _drainTask.Disposable = _scheduler.ScheduleLongRunning(this, DrainLongRunning);
    }

    // Indicate more work is to be done by the drain loop
    if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _wip) == 1L)
    {
        // resume the drain loop waiting on the guard
        lock (_suspendGuard)
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(_suspendGuard);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess this is about the cost of fences. `Volatile.Read` uses a half fence (acquire) whilst `Interloceked.CompareExchange` is a full fence (acquire and release). It looks like they're trying to avoid the full fence in the case where `_runDrainOnce` isn't  0.

Comment: According to Eric Lippert [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192124/reference-assignment-is-atomic-so-why-is-interlocked-exchangeref-object-object): "Interlocked.Exchange is written to expect a volatile field and do the right thing" which seems to mean that it's not necessary to do the volatile read first (assuming the same applies to CompareExchange()). I can't see the source, but I'd guess it does a volatile read equivalent inside the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entirely speculative possibility follows. In reality, I'd say that *without explicit benchmarking*, it probably *doesn't matter*, and we could simply lose the `Volatile.Read` test, or even just use a `lock`. If there *was* explicit benchmarking, I'd hope for a comment hinting (or linking) at that.

---

We can infer from the naming (`_runDrainOnce`) that we only expect this to *succeed* once, and if something is only going to succeed once, we really don't need the success case to be super optimal - so: having a redundant test in that success path: not a huge problem. In contrast, let's speculate that the *failure* scenario is called *many many times*, and so having it fail *just* doing an acquire-fenced read (without attempting to write) *may* be beneficial.

The `Schedule` code is invoked by *everything* - see `OnCompleted`, `OnError`, `OnNext`, etc - so presumably the intent is to just make sure that the scheduling *gets started*, as efficiently as possible - so it doesn't touch `Intelocked` more than necessary (once successfully, and possibly a few times indicating
failure, if there is high thread competition initially)

---

You didn't explicitly ask, but the `lock`/`Pulse` is a common pattern for having an idle worker loop waiting on receiving work using `Monitor`; you need to wake it *if* it was likely idle, which is when the count *was* zero and is now non-zero (hence the `Interlocked.Increment`).

Comment: Thanks Marc. It's that phenomenon where there are just one too many words you don't quite understand which makes it so you don't understand the whole sentence.